# How is this variable being cached in this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have inherited some MVC code from another developer. 
There is a static class called DataCache that contains lots of methods a bit like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<EntityFieldsList> UserGroupsFields()
{
    if (Cache["userGroupFields"] is List<EntityFieldsList> userGroupFields) return userGroupFields;

    ...some code...

    Cache.Set("userGroupFields", userGroupFields, policy);
    return userGroupFields;
}
```

I don't understand how that first line works.

How is the variable `userGroupFields` being declared as part of the `IS` comparison?

And then how does it have a value for it to be returned immediately on the same line? Surely it will always be `null`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Cache["userGroupFields"] is List<EntityFieldsList> userGroupFields)
```

In English, if the return value of `Cache["userGroupFields"]` is `List<EntityFieldsList>`, then define `List<EntityFieldsList> userGroupFields`

It uses The `is` type pattern to provide the implementation of a type's `IComparable.CompareTo(Object)` method.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is)

---

the last part of your code is definitely not working if there is no global static variable named `userGroupFields`. [Check This](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1eClSY)

Comment: and if the condition is not true then the variable does not get defined?  it is used later in the code regardless, so that doesn't make sense

Comment: also, wouldn't the value always be null upon declaration?

Comment: when the if condition is not satisfied it will not get into it, that is why return statement in if block is not called. so the execution continues

Comment: yes but the lines after the if block also refer to the userGroupFields variable, how is that possible if it wasn't declared?

Comment: `Cache.Set("userGroupFields", userGroupFields, policy);` definitely cannot work. check my edit

Comment: please see my answer to own question and this sample code ... The above answer is partly correct, but in fact the IS operator does declare the variable regardless if the condition is true.

See here for an example, try swapping the first two lines
https://dotnetfiddle.net/biC0ks

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is partly correct, but in fact the `IS` operator does declare the variable regardless if the condition is true or not.

See here for an example, try swapping the first two lines
https://dotnetfiddle.net/biC0ks

Comment: The fiddle doesn't prove your assumption. The assignment in `else` is within the scope of the `if` statement, making it available outside when you print its value. If you comment out the assignment in the `else` statement you get a compilation error: _Use of unassigned local variable '`b`'_

Answer (score 0):

This is the so-called [*type pattern*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#-type-pattern-) of the `is` keyword, and takes the form:

```
expr is type varname
```

> where *expr* is an expression that evaluates to an instance of some type, *type* is the name of the type to which the result of expr is to be converted, and *varname* is the object to which the result of _expr) is converted if the `is` test is true.
>   The is expression is true if *expr* is not null, and any of the following is true:
>
> - *expr* is an instance of the same type as *type*.
> - expr is an instance of a type that derives from *type*. In other words, the result of *expr* can be upcast to an instance of *type*.
> - *expr* has a compile-time type that is a base class of *type*, and *expr* has a runtime type that is *type* or is derived from *type*. The compile-time type of a variable is the variable's type as defined in its declaration. The runtime type of a variable is the type of the instance that is assigned to that variable.
> - *expr* is an instance of a type that implements the *type* interface.
>
> **If *expr* is true and `is` is used with an if statement, *varname* is assigned and has local scope within the if statement only.**

(emphasis mine)